# How to stream RTSP video stream using AWS KVS to browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have a source which generates RTSP stream. I am sending the RTP packets to Amazon Kinesis Video Stream. My client is a web browser were I want to play the video stream. How can I relay the stream which is in the KVS to HTML5 video player?

Also is there any other ways then using Kinesis Video Stream?